# How do I populate child elements in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, soap, xml-parsing

I have an xml (Foo.xml)template which is defined as follows:

```
<Parent:Request xmlns:user="http://xxx.com/">
<Parent:ElemA></Parent:ElemA>
<Parent:ChildNode>
    <ElemB></ElemB>
    <ElemC></ElemC>
</Parent:ChildNode>
<Parent:ParentName></Parent:ParentName>
</Parent:Request>
```

In my code, I am able to set the parent elements in the xmltemplate as follows:

```
public void FooA( MyDomainObject DoM)
{
    private readonly XNamespace myNS = "http://ANameSpace.com/";
    XElement fooRequestDoc = XElement.Load("Templates/Foo.xml");

    XElement ElemA_El = fooRequestDoc.Descendants(myNS + "ElemA").FirstOrDefault();
    ElemA_El.SetValue(DoM.ElemA); 
}
```

In this case, if ElemA has a value of "ElementA", then the ElemA_El parameter would be set to this value.

My question is, how do I set a specific Child Note elements such as ElemB or ElemC?

I've tried using "Element" (since I understand it's used to retreive child elements) as follows:

```
XElement ElemB_El = fooRequestDoc.Element(myNS + "ChildNode");
```

But it's returning the entire block rather than just ElemB which I seek.

Comment: how is this related to linq and soap?

Comment: @Doorknob I disagree with you. I dont lose focus when reading things like that.

Comment: @JensKloster [others do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/147063 "Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?")

Comment: @JensKloster However, it is generally frowned upon in this community.

Comment: @Default I guess people in here gets easy distracted :) I was unawere that a vote had taken place on whether to be polite or not. Lets not discuss this further in the coments - i'm open for a chat if you feel the need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name of the tag you could do something like this:

```
XElement ElemB_El = (from node in fooRequestDoc.Descendants() where node.Name == myNS + "ElemB" select node).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you don't know the name of the tag you can take every Descendants of ChildNode like this:

```
var nodes = (from node in fooRequestDoc.Descendants(myNS + "ChildNode").Elements() select node).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions, Machel. Both are great and the first is really what I am looking for. However, the syntax is a bit off. Can you please update it so that it compiles?

Comment: Sorry, missed the = sign and the open parentheses.